# telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found

Tags: python, tkinter

i made a program to send photos to telegram and when i send to telegram there is an error. Previously I made a GUI to fill in the API fields and the message delivery destination column but when I sent a message my program seemed not to know where the message was sent. so i found that the address field will be changed to string variable automatically..how do i solve this??

[my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PV2T.png)

[label3 of address and Penerima Entry of address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqqiz.png)

[i get the entry of the address as tujuan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTOOK.png)

[i send photo with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72BD5.png)

Comment: A 404 error generally means you are trying to access a resource that doesn’t exist. This likely means that the chat id you are trying to send it to does not exist, so it’s possible your chat id is incorrect or has changed since you first found it. It also could be that your client is not allowed to access that chat and so the api is preventing it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that **the specified chat was not found in the Telegram API**. The problem could be one of these:

1. **Wrong Chat ID:** Make sure you have correctly provided the ID of the
   chat you are trying to send the message to. Check if the chat ID was
   obtained correctly and if it was used in the request.
2. **Chat archived or deleted:** If your chat has been archived or deleted,
   you may get this error. Check the status of the chat in your
   Telegram client to make sure it's still active.
3. **Insufficient Permission:** Make sure the bot has the necessary
   permissions to send messages in the specified chat. Check your bot's
   permission settings to make sure it's allowed to send messages in
   the target chat.

In my case, by mistake, I took the key of another service instead of the bot's key. Check carefully that it is the correct one.
Otherwise try asking here: [**pyTelegramBotAPI**](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) if you use this repo.

If you have a long code with several keys, it's easy to make a mistake. I recommend using a simplified version of the code to see if it works.

For example, try running this and see if the message arrives:

**Copy the key directly from botfather so you don't make any mistakes.**

```py
import telebot

TOKEN = 'YOUR TOKEN'
chat_id = YOUR CHAT ID

#create a new Telegram Bot object
tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# sendMessage
tb.send_message(chat_id, "Text")
```